# How do you avoid different layout of Shape-objects on screen and printed out?

Tags: vba, excel

I created some kind of phone protocol sheet in excel and I wanted to add a section with quadrille paper for sketching purposes. Therefore I wrote a quite simple macro in VBA that draws horizontal and vertical lines in a selected range:

```
Public Sub Fill()

    Dim angepeilteMaschenWeiteInPixel As Integer
    angepeilteMaschenWeiteInPixel = 15

    Dim LinienFarbe As Long
    LinienFarbe = RGB(220, 220, 220)

    Dim obenLinks As Double, obenRechts As Double
    Dim untenLinks As Double, untenRechts As Double
    Dim ausgewaehlteRange As Range

    Set ausgewaehlteRange = Selection

    ' Anzahl Spalten und Zeilen ermitteln bei idealer Breite/Höhe 10px

    Dim idealeSpaltenAnzahl As Integer
    Dim idealeZeilenAnzahl As Integer

    idealeSpaltenAnzahl = CInt(Round((ausgewaehlteRange.Width / angepeilteMaschenWeiteInPixel), 0))
    idealeZeilenAnzahl = CInt(Round((ausgewaehlteRange.Height / angepeilteMaschenWeiteInPixel), 0))

    ' Aus der idealen Spalten- und Zeilenanzahl die ideale Maschenweite und - höhe in Pixeln ermitteln

    Dim idealeMaschenBreite As Double
    Dim idealeMaschenHoehe As Double

    idealeMaschenBreite = ausgewaehlteRange.Width / CDbl(idealeSpaltenAnzahl)
    idealeMaschenHoehe = ausgewaehlteRange.Height / CDbl(idealeZeilenAnzahl)

    ' vertikale Linien zeichnen

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To idealeSpaltenAnzahl - 1

        Dim horizontal As Integer
        horizontal = CInt(ausgewaehlteRange.Left + i * idealeMaschenBreite)

        Dim oben As Integer
        oben = Round(ausgewaehlteRange.Top, 0)

        Dim unten As Integer
        unten = Round(oben + ausgewaehlteRange.Height, 0)


        With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddLine(horizontal, oben, horizontal, unten).Line
            .ForeColor.RGB = LinienFarbe



        End With

    Next i

    ' horizontale Linien zeichnen

    Dim j As Integer


    For j = 1 To idealeZeilenAnzahl - 1

        Dim vertikal As Integer
        vertikal = CInt(ausgewaehlteRange.Top + j * idealeMaschenHoehe)

        Dim links As Integer
        links = CInt(Round(ausgewaehlteRange.Left, 0))

        Dim rechts As Integer
        rechts = CInt(Round(links + ausgewaehlteRange.Width, 0))


        With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddLine(links, vertikal, rechts, vertikal).Line
            .ForeColor.RGB = LinienFarbe



        End With

    Next j

End Sub
```

in excel everything looks fine:

[image: excel screenshot]

but in the print preview and also printed out, the horizontal line gap is uneven and I have no idea why:

[image: print preview screenshot]

Anybody out there who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the lines are moving with the cells.  Try setting the object positioning property to "Don't move or size with cells" which the English value is `xlFreeFloating`.

Example:

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddLine(links, vertikal, rechts, vertikal)
    .Line.ForeColor.RGB = LinienFarbe
    .Placement = xlFreeFloating
End With
```

---

**Edit**

Interesting behavior... I still think it's related to cells & margins as the lines move with cell width changes in print preview even though position is set to freeform.

I did find a workaround by grouping the lines together.

Added three lines of code.  Add the following to both With blocks after Horizontal and Vertical lines are created.

```
.Select Replace:=False
```

Now add this line at the end of the sub:

```
Selection.Group
```

Now all the lines that were just created are grouped together.

Result image from print preview.

[image]

---

Example of last code block for your reference:

```
' horizontale Linien zeichnen
Dim j As Integer

For j = 1 To idealeZeilenAnzahl - 1
    Dim vertikal As Integer
    vertikal = CInt(ausgewaehlteRange.Top + j * idealeMaschenHoehe)

    Dim links As Integer
    links = CInt(Round(ausgewaehlteRange.Left, 0))

    Dim rechts As Integer
    rechts = CInt(Round(links + ausgewaehlteRange.Width, 0))

    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddLine(links, vertikal, rechts, vertikal)
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = LinienFarbe
        .Placement = xlFreeFloating
        .Select Replace:=False
    End With
Next j

Selection.Group
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn´t had any effect. It still looks as in the screenshots posted above.

Comment: Would you be able to share your file via Dropbox or something similar?  Strip out anything confidential.

Comment: Sure, here it is: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2408310/HotlineFormular.xlsm). There are no shortcuts to access the macros yet. There are called "clear" to clear all lines and "fill" to fill the selected range with lines.

Comment: Thanks, take a look at my edit.  I found a work around that might do the trick for you.

Comment: That totally worked and I would have never figured it out myself. Thanks!